# I am facing this error while making a Reinforcement learning model.This error is something about kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1

Comment: Hi, you didn't provide any code for any of us to have a look here. What are you expecting? We don't know how you got the error, where you got the error. Please give some detailed info.

Comment: Your kivy isn't installed properly. Anything else is, as already said, impossible to diagnose from this information alone.